# How does this very long tube deployed from the back of a 787 measure pressure?

Tags: boeing-787

Photos in the CNET's [Up close with the first Boeing 787-9](https://www.cnet.com/pictures/up-close-with-the-first-boeing-787-9-pictures/22/?ftag=ACQ-10-10abh2b&vndid=www.bbc.com) include the one below with the caption

> **Boeing 787-9 at Farnborough** The back of the first 787-9 has coiled tubing extended from the back of the plane's tail during test flights. It's used to measure the true air pressure to compare with the different higher and lower pressures near the plane.

Apparently this is from 2014.

**Question:** What is this kind of tube called, how is it used, what structure is at the far end of the tube when deployed, and why does it need to be so long?

[image: Boeing 787-9 at Farnborough tube to measure air pressure]

Published:July 13, 2014 Caption:Stephen Shankland Photo:Stephen Shankland/CNET

Comment: [Trailing cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trailing_cone). See [What is the purpose of the ball and string attached to the tip of the vertical fin on test aircraft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/14237/3201) or this one which was closed, but seems even better: [What's the purpose of the cable connected on the top of the fin?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25365)

Comment: @Gerry sounds good to me, I've voted to close as well.