# Why do the in house Boeing 737 max tails have a drag chute?

Tags: boeing-737, feature-identification

In the recent videos of some in-house (tagged as Boeing instead of some airline), at the top of the aircraft's tail, there is a rope with a small drag chute attached to it. What is the purpose of this?

The drag chute setup can be seen at 0:15 and 0:30 into this video:

Comment: Which itself is a dupe of https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14237/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-ball-and-string-attached-to-the-tip-of-the-vertical-f So indeed it appears to be an instrument.