# What is that little black thing tied to the vertical stabilizer?

Tags: boeing-737, feature-identification, boeing, flight-testing

[image: 737 Max test plane]

I have seen this on all Boeing test planes, does this provide information on the planes performance?

Comment: Already answered [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/14237/3201) and [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/25365/3201), at least.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That’s a   [**trailing cone.**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trailing_cone)  It hangs out behind the aircraft and serves to calibrate the aircraft’s pitot-static system against static pressure error by providing a static source for ambient air pressure data in clean air well clear of the aircraft. The cone is connected to the aircraft by high-strength pressure tubing to feed the data to the aircraft.